# Php MyAdmin Pulling Data

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple php file for one of my classes.  When I try to display every entry that is in my database, it just spits out the first one....I need any help i can get on how to pull all the rows out. If I have 5 people submit the form, then I need all their information to appear on the page. As of right now, I am only getting 1 person. Here is my Code..

```
 <?php
    require("connecthunter.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hunterinfo";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($result){
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($numrows>0){

        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo "Name: $row[fname] $row[lname] <br>";
        echo "Email: $row[email] <br>";
        echo "Phone Number: $row[phone]  <br>";
        echo "Selling: $row[sell] <br>";
        echo "Price: $row[price]<br>";

    }




}
else {
    die("Unable to query records. Try again.");

}
?>
```

Comment: You have to loop over the results; you can't just call `mysqli_fetch_array()` one time. Also, PHPMyAdmin is not the same as MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no looping to show all item in array.
Change this:

```
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo "Name: $row[fname] $row[lname] <br>";
    echo "Email: $row[email] <br>";
    echo "Phone Number: $row[phone]  <br>";
    echo "Selling: $row[sell] <br>";
    echo "Price: $row[price]<br>";
```

to

```
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


    echo "Name: $row[fname] $row[lname] <br>";
    echo "Email: $row[email] <br>";
    echo "Phone Number: $row[phone]  <br>";
    echo "Selling: $row[sell] <br>";
    echo "Price: $row[price]<br>";

    }
```